# SQL Server GROUP BY with 2 tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by

I would like to know how I can create this GROUP BY clause, here are the 2 tables:

[image]

An order can have multiple vehicles linked to it via `Order.Id` => `OrderVehicle.OrderId`.
What I would like to archive is create a query that will detect possible order duplicates and getting an error because I am using `Order.Id` column to link to `OrderVehicle.OrderId` column, here's my attempt:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS [Total],
    CAST(o.[CreatedOn] AS DATE),
    o.[Amount],
    o.[OrderTypeId]
FROM
    [dbo].[Order] o
GROUP BY
    CAST(o.[CreatedOn] AS DATE),
    o.[Amount],
    o.[OrderTypeId]
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

This query is supposed to find orders which are the same amount (`[Order].[Amount]`), created on the same day (`[Order].[CreatedOn]`), are the same order type (`[Order].[OrderTypeId]`) as well as the existence of such is > 1 (`HAVING COUNT(1) > 1`).

The above query works as is, the problem comes in when I need to include the Order Vehicles on the order if this `[Order].[OrderTypeId]` is one where a user can select vehicle (s). What I wish to archive is combine the `[dbo].[OrderVehicle].[VehicleId]` such as concating it in sub select, e.g. if `Order.Id` 25 is linked to 3 `OrderVehicles` then the Group By clause must `CONCAT` the 3 `OrderVehicles` on `[dbo].[OrderVehicle].[VehicleId]` column.

Is this possible, if so how can I archive something like that? Or should I go about this differently? Thanks and much appreciated in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and table structure

Comment: You can do this with Partition By. Using windows function is better than using Having and groups

Comment: Thanks guys, I will test both solutions and see if it helps me

Comment: @Tyron78 I have updated the question with table structure

Comment: @Morgs I edited my answer. I used only two tables. I am giving you the logic to get your work is done. You can join any number of tables by based on your requirement.   Have a look and let me know if you need any helps :) Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create a CTE on the Vehicles table, which uses XMP PATH in order to concat your Vehicle list. AN example:

```
DECLARE @tOrderVehicle TABLE(
ID int, OrderID int, VehicleID int
)

INSERT INTO @tOrderVehicle VALUES
(1, 1, 1)
,(2, 1, 2)
,(3, 1, 3)
,(4, 2, 1)
,(5, 2, 4)
,(6, 3, 1)
,(7, 3, 2)
,(8, 3, 3)


;WITH cteOrderVehicles AS(
select OrderID, STUFF(
        (SELECT  ',' + CAST(a.VehicleID AS VARCHAR(100))  AS [text()]
        from @tOrderVehicle  a
        where a.OrderID = b.OrderID
        Order by a.VehicleID
        for xml PATH('')),1,1,''       ) AS Vehicles_Concatenated
 from @tOrderVehicle b
group by b.OrderID
)
SELECT *
  FROM cteOrderVehicles
ORDER BY OrderID
```

If you join this to your order table, you should be able to consider the vehicles in your group by as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to use windows function. With that, this is very simple. and you can have your results easily. Row_Number() is used to filter out duplicate partitions from the final result.

```
  CREATE TABLE [order] 
  (
  id INT
  ,amount INT
  ,[OrderTypeId] int 
   )

 create table vehicleOrder
 (
 id int primary key
 ,order_id int
 ,createdOn DATE
 ,vehicleId int    
  )

INSERT INTO [order] VALUES(1,200000, 1)
 ,(2,40000, 1)
 ,(3,2006000, 1)
 ,(4,56777,3)
 ,(5,145887, 4)
 ,(2,40000, 1)
 ,(3,2006000, 1)
  ,(1,200000, 1)

 INSERT INTO vehicleOrder VALUES(1,1,'02/05/2016',200000)
 ,(2,1,'02/05/2016',40000)
 ,(3,2,'02/06/2016',2006000)
 ,(4,1,'02/06/2016',56777)
 ,(5,3,'07/06/2016',145887)
 ,(6,2,'02/05/2016',40000)
 ,(7,3,'02/06/2016',2006000)
 ,(8,1,'02/05/2016',200000)


 SELECT *
 FROM
  (
      SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY   CAST(vo.[CreatedOn] AS DATE) ,  o.[Amount],    o.[OrderTypeId] ORDER BY  vo.[CreatedOn] ) as [rn] 
        , COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY   CAST(vo.[CreatedOn] AS DATE) ,  o.[Amount],    o.[OrderTypeId] ORDER BY   vo.[CreatedOn] ) as [Count]
        ,  CAST(vo.[CreatedOn] AS DATE) [CreatedOn]
        , o.[Amount]
        , o.[OrderTypeId]

     FROM   [order]   o 
     INNER JOIN  vehicleOrder vo 
        ON O.id = vo.order_id
  ) AS A 
  WHERE A.[Count] > 1 AND A.rn = 1
```

[image: Result]

I am giving you the logic, how to get the aggregation by based on partition. With multiple columns.

Comment: I tried your solution and it looks you mixed up the columns. The `Amount` and `OrderTypeId` are in the `Order` table and not the `OrderVehicle` table so your solution doesn't run when I try it... I will update the question with a SQL diagram for the 2 tables

Comment: My answer was based on what you have posted earlier. I will edit it and post for your convenience, @Morgs

Comment: You can select what ever columns you want from the derived table.  I have selected all columns.  @Morgs

Comment: thanks will try your recommended solution

Comment: @Morgs Let me know any support needed. Happy to help you!!